# Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GestorContenidoWS' did not find a matching property. Try all the solutions

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

This is my first post here (but not the first time that I visit the page, I found a lot of solutions here), first of all, sorry for my english I will try to explain myself as best I can.

This question appears another time in this page, but I tried all the solutions that the people post and I still with this problem, well here we go.

I made a project on Eclipse(indigo) for launch like a WebService (I did it before with succes, is not my first time) and when I Run on Server(Tomcat7) all seems fine and the appears this Warning.

```
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GestorContenidoWS' did not find a matching property.
```

Then appear in the Web perspective of Eclipse the page "HTTP 404". I'm telling this because I read in other post that this Warning is not a problem, but seems that it is for me (The project is also vinculated with a JPA Persistence).

.I found two solutions for make dissappear this Warning. First, go to Server Overview and select the option 'Publish module contexts to separate XML files' and then try to Run on server again, but didn't work.

The other option was, remove the project from the server from the Server View. Then run the project under the same server for recreated server.xml, but didn't work also.

Anybody can help me? Maybe the problem of this "HTTP 404 requested resource (/GestorContenidoWS/) is not available." is in another part or its because this Warning?"

The code of my server.xml (without comments) is this:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved"                    factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
 <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080"  protocol="HTTP/1.1"redirectPort="8443"/>
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>
  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

  <Context docBase="GestorContenidoWS" path="/GestorContenidoWS" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GestorContenidoWS"/></Host>
</Engine>
  </Service>
```

Thank you

Comment: is `source` in type `GestorContenidoWS` accessible (public/setSource)?

Comment: Sorry Marco Forberg, I don't understand very well your question, 'source' appear in 'server.xml' like "source=org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GestorContenidoWS", you mean that?

Comment: that means you try to set the `source` property of some bean to `org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GestorContenidoWS`. Please show the code of your `server.xml` and the bean you modify

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the exact issue it's driving me crazy. Have tried everything. Please if you've resolved it explain how so we can do the same.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First of all this is a warning and not an error. So there is no need to worry too much about it. Basically it means, that Tomcat does not know what to do with the source attribute from context.

This source attribute is set by Eclipse (or to be more specific the Eclipse Web Tools Platform) to the server.xml file of Tomcat to match the running application to a project in workspace.

Tomcat generates a warning for every unknown markup in the server.xml (i.e. the source attribute) and this is the source of the warning. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: ennu thaamasikyumoo..??

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning and can be safely ignored. Tomcat or the Web container does not understand what to do with the property set by Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

set contex-root

```
<property name="context-root" value="path" />
```

and http://localhost:8080/path
show your index file

Answer (score 0):

Find server.xml. For example "C:\Dev\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\conf\server.xml"

Find your application in server.xml

```
 <Context docBase="C:\Dev\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\wtpwebapps\SpringRestExample" path="/spring" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringRestExample"/></Host>
```

Expected url http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample/rest/emp/9999

But (path="/spring") instead (path="/SpringRestExample")

Therefore current url http://localhost:8080/spring/rest/emp/9999