# Which jar file i should import for mysql 5.6.24

Tags: java, mysql, jelastic

mysql 5.6.24 database is hosted in jelastic for java program which jar file i need to import.i have imported mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin is this a correct jar file.

Please suggest me..

this is the error it is showing..

```
Aug 19, 2015 9:09:56 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FetchingRecord' did not find a matching property.    
Aug 19, 2015 9:09:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener  
log  
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.62  
Aug 19, 2015 9:09:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener  
log      
INFO: Server built:          May 7 2015 17:14:55 UTC
Aug 19, 2015 9:09:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener  
log
```

Thanks..

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Sounds right, or use the latest, which is 5.1.36 at the moment.

Comment: I have update the description @Thilo

Answer (score 2):

Mysql Connector/J version 5.1 supports 
MySQL Server versions 4.1, 5.0, 5.1, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7

So it should be fine.

```
Table listing Summary of Connector/J Versions

Connector/J version     JDBC version        MySQL Server version                Status
5.1                     3.0, 4.0            4.1, 5.0, 5.1, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7    Recommended version
5.0                     3.0                 4.1, 5.0                        Released version
3.1                     3.0                 4.1, 5.0                        Obsolete
3.0                     3.0                 3.x, 4.1                        Obsolete
```

More information can be obtained from the mysql documentation page

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-versions.html

if you are worried about the line

```
WARNING: Setting property 'source' to org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:FetchingRecord' did not find a matching property.
```

Then this is a warning. Most probably it would not cause an issue.

**Most common solution suggested for errors of the format**

**Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:xxx' did not find a matching property.**

**is below**

- Open your tomcat server.
- In the "Server Options" part, check    "Publish module contexts to
  separate XML files.
- Restart.

The below links in SO has many answers for similar errors which could help you.

[Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSFTut' did not find a matching property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566146/setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverjsftut-did-not-find-a)

[WARNING: Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:appname' did not find a matching property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278009/warning-setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverappname-did-n)

[Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GestorContenidoWS' did not find a matching property. Try all the solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416420/setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-servergestorcontenidows-did)